# Is this a grammar issue or am I understanding it wrong?

Tags: rust, borrowing

I'm reading the book [*Programming Rust*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920040385.do). There are some places I don't quite understand.

---

Example 1

For this code

```
fn main() {
    let r;
    {
        let x = 1;
        r = &x;
    }
    println!("{:?}", r);
}
```

The author states

> In this example, there are three lifetimes whose relationships we need to work out. The variables r and x each have a lifetime, extending from the point at which they’re initialized until the point that they go out of scope. The third lifetime is that of a reference type: the type of the reference we **borrow to** &x, and store in r.

---

Example 2

For this code

```
let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
let r = &v[1];
```

The author states

> These rules apply in a natural way when you **borrow a reference to** some part of some larger data structure, like an element of a vector:

---

Example 3

> You can **“borrow a reference”** to a value; references are nonowning pointers, with limited lifetimes.

Note here the quotes are in the text of the book, not added by me.

---

Note the bold text in the description of the two examples. Why the author always say *borrow sth to sth* instead of *borrow sth from sth*? I'm not a native English speaker and as I understand *borrow sth from sth/sb* is the correct usage. When talking about Rust's reference borrowing, is this usage correct?

Comment: I'd say the first part is worded a bit confusingly. You can read it as *"the type of the reference to &x we borrow and store in r"*. You're right that "borrow to" isn't really correct here, but you can "borrow **a reference to**" something

Comment: Don't overthink it. In both cases, you can read it as "**a reference to sth**" and then we are here to "**borrow that reference**". In the meantime, shouldn't this be closed?

Comment: @edwardw I don't know:-) Haha, I just want to bring it up to let the Rust professionals take a look.

Comment: @kmdreko Thanks, that's reasonable. I added example 3 and it's not the same as example 2.

Comment: To clarify edwardw's point, you should read these as "borrow (a reference to a value)" rather than "(borrow a reference) to a value". This wording deviates from the usual wording in the Rust documentation and the compiler error messages. I'd usually say "the reference creates a borrow of the value", or "you borrow the value" (by creating a reference). "Borrowing a reference" sounds a bit off to me.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Yes, I understand it. Thanks for the clarification. But in example 3, the author said: “borrow a reference” to a value. The quotes are part of the text from the book.

Comment: I think Example 1 is substantially different from the other two, and I even suspect it's a victim of editing: I would say the reference being borrowed is **to `x`** (`&x` is the reference, `x` is the thing being referenced, so `&x` is **a reference to `x`**. I suggest re-reading Example 1 assuming it was meant to be written without the `&`. Does that help? (I have the book, but I haven't looked through to see if it uses this convention anywhere else)